# alias with sudo not working

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm trying to add an alias to my .bashrc `alias oops='sudo !!'` when i execute it however I get:

`sudo: !!: command not found`

eliminating the alias from the .bashrc and im able to manually use sudo !!, why does this happen?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try with:

```
alias oops='sudo $(history -p !!)'
```